# getting id of literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working Asp.net and c#.

In my application i have a **Autocomplete textbox** with literal control.I need to get the **Id** of that literal control in my codebehind,but i couldn't get because there is no **runat** attribute.If i use runat attribute my Autocomplete is not working.please give me some sugessions to solve this problem.

code:

```
      <input ID="txtrecipient"/>
```

***Note**:I need the id **txtrecipient** in codebehind.

Comment: You need to use a textbox servercontrol for the input instead of a literal to access it in codebehind. If this causes problems with the ID then that is a separate problem to be solved afterwards.

Comment: I tried using tectbox control,if i use it autocomplete is not working.

Comment: @DJKRAZE if i use runat attribute my autocomplete is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is using server control with attribute runat="server" and set its ClientIDMode=Static.

If you don't want to change ClientIDMode, you can also access the client id of the textbox on client side. See below example:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("<%= txtrecipient.ClientID %>").value = "";
     ... or
     $("<%= txtrecipient.ClientID %>").autoComeplete();
</script>
```